# Importing an Interface in Typescript from another file

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, interface, lerna

How do you import an interface from another file?

If I use `type` I can do the following:

```
// branch.ts
export type Branch = {
  colour: string
}

// tree.ts
import {Branch} from "./branch"
type Tree = {
  branch: Branch[]
}
```

Whereas with `interface` it complains about it not being a namespace `[ts] Cannot use namespace 'Branch' as a type.`:

```
// branch.ts
export interface Branch {
  colour: string
}

// tree.ts
import {Branch} from "./branch"
interface Tree {
  branch: Branch[]
}
```

Project structure:

I cant publish the repo sorry, but here is the setup we have. We are using lerna so we are declaring modules in an `index.d.ts` file e.g. `declare module "@shared/branch"`. It looks like tslint it can't find the interface export properly so complains. The code compiles and runs as expected though

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.  Can you publish a complete repository that reproduces it for you?

Comment: Hi @MattMcCutchen, I have can't share the repo unfortunately, but I have added information about our project above. Cheers

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't ring a bell with me.  You may have to minimize the example yourself by deleting stuff until either the problem goes away or you are left with nothing confidential and can publish the tree.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen, I'll take a look into Typesecript in monorepo's as I have a feeling it's related to this! Thanks though!